# Why this html anchor tag is not auto clicking Javascript link?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, href

Here is the html of anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myid">JavaScript Link Code</a>
```

And this is the Javascript function's statement (not Javascript link code) which I am using

```
simulate(document.getElementById("myid"), "click");
```

Please help me. I want to auto click 'Javascript Link Code' between `<a> </a>` when page loads.

Comment: Javascript does not have a `simulate` function.

Comment: did you search for this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722863/how-to-click-a-link-from-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826458/auto-click-an-anchor-link-on-the-page-when-the-page-is-visited

Comment: But the anchor just has a `void(0)` statement, so it's not going to do anything anyway...

Comment: @nnn then what should i put instead of `void(0)`

Comment: What do you want the link to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function on load, there is a simple way.

```
window.onload = function() {
  someCode();  // call here whatever JavaScript Code you want on load
};
```

Why try to 'simulate' a click only to call its function?

You can get and execute the code like this

```
var code = document.getElementById('myid').textContent;
eval(code);
```

But it's not wise to execute code like this.