# ember acceptance test for mouse draggable actions

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing

> As we have ember helpers for all events, how can i cover my drag and
>   drop events in the components through acceptance test ? Provide a test
>   with some working example.

Comment: Good question. A related more general question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15653026/1804173

Comment: Looking for the same thing

Comment: Have you tried syn library?

Comment: No. I haven't tried