# Mouse click simulates keyboard key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, touch, dom-events, key-bindings

I have situation that in application (HTML/XUL) there are key bindings for some function keys (<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F9</kbd>) in order to communicate with some other application.

Now I have to make touch-based interface for same app, without keyboard and advanced touch events. All touch clicks are actually same as mouse clicks and I need to have 3 buttons/links that behave same as <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F9</kbd> keys.

Don't ask for reasons, all I can say is that I need to keep that key bindings.

Can I assign mouse click on link to act like F-key is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jake's answer is most of solution and based on that I gave the whole answer, because is not so easy on first glance for beginners to modify functionality.
This is modified function from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158160/1235841):

```
function simulateKeyPress(target, options) {
    var event = target.ownerDocument.createEvent('KeyEvents'),
        options = options || {};

    // Set your options or || default values
    var opts = {
        type: options.type                  || "keypress",
        bubbles: options.bubbles            || true,
        cancelable: options.cancelable      || true,
        viewArg: options.viewArg            || null,
        ctrlKeyArg: options.ctrlKeyArg      || false,
        altKeyArg: options.altKeyArg        || false,
        shiftKeyArg: options.shiftKeyArg    || false,
        metaKeyArg: options.metaKeyArg      || false,
        keyCodeArg: options.keyCodeArg      || 0,
        charCodeArg: options.charCodeArg    || 0
    }

    // Pass in the options
    event.initKeyEvent(
        opts.type,
        opts.bubbles,
        opts.cancelable,
        opts.viewArg,
        opts.ctrlKeyArg,
        opts.altKeyArg,
        opts.shiftKeyArg,
        opts.metaKeyArg,
        opts.keyCodeArg,
        opts.charCodeArg
    );

    // Fire the event
    target.dispatchEvent(event);
    event.stopPropagation;
}
```

And now we call it on desired element/event for desired key to be pressed. Second argument is object with all options changeable (in my case keyCodeArg: 116 is only needed to be send to simulate F5 key press).

```
document.getElementById(element).addEventListener('click', function() {
    simulateKeyPress(this, {keyCodeArg: 116});
});
```

Mozilla Developer Network has nice articles about [KeyboardEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) and [initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initKeyEvent).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this I guess.

The simple way would be to have your F-keys call a function, and simply call the same function  when catching a mouse event.

The other way would be to catch the mouse event, and fire a F-key press event. Then it would pretty much be a duplicate of this question:

[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript)

Comment: Tnx, You've navigated me to the answer. I had to take a little bit effort and because of that gave an exact answer to my own question to help someone in future.