# Simulate Command Key 91 (mac) held down constantly

Tags: javascript, html, command, keypress, simulate

I've searched and searched, but unable to find the solution.

I'm wanting to simulate the command key `91` & `93` `keypress` held down constantly on the page, that no matter what happens on the page, even `clicks`, the command key will always be simulated as held down.

How is this possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303965/mouse-click-simulates-keyboard-key-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846687/javascript-simulate-keyboard-events-work-on-chromewebkit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396182/simulate-holding-ctrl-key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background