# How does one programmatically click a button via the browser console [code inside]

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, I am able to click some links/buttons, but cannot for buttons/anything that has an onclick attribute.
For example:
my JavaScript code I input into the browser's console:

```
var o = document.getElementsByName("takepic"); 
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    o.click();
    console.log(i);
}
```

I put console.log so I know what the browser is doing, and where it currently is at.

The html code on the page:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Configure..." onclick="webcam.configure()">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()" name="takepic">
</form>
```

So basically, I want to take rapid snapshots using the browser console, but when I enter in my code, I get this error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'click'

When I do use the same code, say for re-adding friends on facebook, and I use this:

```
var o = document.getElementsByName("fbaddfriend_example"); 
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
    o[i].click(); 
    console.log(i);
}
```

It definitely works.
I'm just trying to do the same with a button on a page, but with no avail.

Comment: Yup, but for some reason SOF puts them in separate lines [which is pretty cool].

Comment: Some element types do have a `click` method, some don't. See duplicate of [How to simulate mouse click using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
var o = document.getElementsByName("takepic"); 
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
// ---v
    o[i].click();
    console.log(i);
}
```

The variable `o` holds a collection of all retrieved elements. `o[i]` returns the element at position `i`.

Comment: Nice, I should have tried adding that array of i to o. It works, but it clicks just once. It doesn't continue. an error spits out too: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined"

EDIT: Oh, I think it's because i is being added 1 to it, and since there's only one element, i should just hardcode "1" in o[1].click() .... I'll try this out, and I'll get back to you

Comment: @JeromieDevera if there is only one element, give it an id, and then use `document.getElementById()`. Then you don't have to worry about referencing an array index. Also, arrays are zero-indexed. If there is only one, the index is 0.

Comment: @JeromieDevera The loop runs 1000 times, but the array `o` contains fewer elements. Consider Bic's code which clicks each button 1000 times.

Comment: I added 0 since it was a 0 index (starts at 0) and it worked! Thanks for explaining further what the getElementsByName method really did. Really helped.

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is in the code you're typing into the console. You are using `document.getElementsByName()`, which will return an array of elements. You need to loop through those elements. You are doing this in your second code segment, but not your first.

```
var o = document.getElementsByName("takepic"); 
for (var j = 0; j < o.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        o[j].click();
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```