# Is it possible to trigger mouse middle click event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I want to trigger mouse middle click event using javascript. Is it possible to trigger mouse middle click using Javascript?

I want it because it is pasting last selected object from clipboard.

Thanks, Jimit

Comment: Probably you have a answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same question, did a lot of digging, and this is what I ended up using:

```
if ( window.CustomEvent ) {
    var middleClick = new MouseEvent( "click", { "button": 1, "which": 2 });
    jQuery(".selector")[0].dispatchEvent( middleClick );
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065688/trigger-native-browser-behavior-for-middle-click-on-a-link?noredirect=1#comment69338498_41065688

Comment: For me this even worked on a link that is not part of the DOM.. but this could be browser-dependent.

Comment: If I do this on an anchor tag, shouldn't the window stay focused and not focus on the newly opened tab/window?@donquixote

Comment: For a middle-click, I think "which" should be 2, not 1.

Comment: @Doin looks like 1 is correct for middle button according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: That's correct for "button".  "which" uses a different numbering scheme:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which

Comment: @Doin oh yea you're right. That's weird, ok I'll update the answer, thanks!

Comment: sadly, on a link element (<a>), this would only work (nearly work, would open a new foreground tab instead of a background one) in chromium, and would have no effect in firefox nor jsfiddle ...

Comment: however, somewhat strangely, using `ctrlKey` instead would work in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf319st8/) (and still half-work in chromium ...

Comment: BTW, tested with `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('auxclick', {button: 1}))`, would and only would trigger the auxclick event, but not any effect on link (for all three platforms above ...

Comment: @laoyb I never noticed the foreground/background difference on chrome, but I see what you mean now. A real middle-click opens in background, but `{ "button": 1, "which": 2 }` opens in foreground.
I opened your fiddle in Firefox, and for me it worked correctly there - the new tab was opened in the background, just like a real middle-click. I haven't needed to test this in ages.. for me the foreground/background thing isn't an issue

Answer (score -3):

You can use

[event.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.button)

to identify which mouse button was clicked.

Returns an integer value indicating the button that changed state.

```
* 0 for standard 'click', usually left button
* 1 for middle button, usually wheel-click
* 2 for right button, usually right-click

  Note that this convention is not followed in Internet Explorer: see 
  QuirksMode for details.
```

The order of buttons may be different depending on how the pointing device has been configured.

Also read

[Which mouse button has been clicked?](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)

> There are two properties for finding
>   out which mouse button has been
>   clicked: which and button. Please note
>   that these properties don’t always
>   work on a click event. To safely
>   detect a mouse button you have to use
>   the mousedown or mouseup events.

Comment: Not what the OP wants - he needs to _trigger_ it, not retrieve the type.