# Trigger native browser behavior for (middle) click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click

### Question

I want to trigger a (middle) mouse click on a link, in a way that triggers the native browser behavior for this event.

E.g. in those browsers I work with, middle-click will cause the linked page to open in a new tab in the background.

But if other browsers have a different behavior, that should be triggered instead.

I know there is the `element.click();` method, but how do I tell it which mouse button should be clicked?

### Background

The background is that I want to make a div behave as much as possible like a regular link. The idea was that I would create a hidden link tag and trigger the native browser behavior.

Requirements for the div-as-a-link:

- href can come from a data-href attribute.
- Native browser behavior for left-click, middle-click and possibly right-click.
- respect of the target attribute, which could come from a data-target attribute.
- tabindex
- activation with the keyboard?
- possibility to select text snippets within the div. This means we cannot just use an overlay.

Why not use a native link tag? Because the div contains inner `<a>` tags. So making the div box an a-tag would cause nested a-tags which would cause some browsers to restructure the DOM tree.

Obviously I could just set document.location.href on click. But this is only 20% of the browser's native behavior.

I could also try to detect the mouse button, and use js to open the tab in the background, if it was the middle button.

But maybe some browsers have a different behavior for middle-click. I would rather let the browser do its thing, than trying to replicate a specific browser behavior with js.

The idea I had was to create a hidden `<a>` tag with the same href, and delegate click events from the `<div>` to this hidden `<a>` tag. For this, I need to trigger the event with the same mouse button. I am not sure how to do this.

### js or jQuery?

jQuery is ok for my personal use case. But to make this useful to a wider audience, maybe also post how to do it without jQuery, if you know.

### See also

There are some question which deal with this kind of problem, but each of them looks at a different angle or has different constraints.

Comment: Try this solution from another SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32868971

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21224428/2694511

Comment: @JonUleis Awesome! Could I simply send the existing click event from the div to the dispatchEvent(), or do I need to create a new event object?

Comment: @SpencerDoak This tells me how to detect the mouse button but not how to trigger such an event. But anyway this is also useful.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Your link is for detecting clicks, not triggering them like OP asked. @donquixote You'll have to experiment and see - might take a little finagling (note that they're executing the event on the `[0]` index of the jQ selector, for example).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I come up with thanks to @JonUleis in the comments and @MikeWillis in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868971/246724

```
  $('.linkbox', context).once('linkbox').each(function(e){

    var $linkbox = $(this);
    var href = $linkbox.data('href');
    if (!href) {
      return;
    }
    var $hiddenLink = $('<a>').attr('href', href).hide().appendTo('body');
    $linkbox.click(function(e){
      $hiddenLink[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {button: e.button, which: e.which}));
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Note that I put the hidden link outside of the clicked div, to prevent recursion.

The right-click menu does not give me "copy link url", but I imagine this would be really hard to replicate.

UPDATE: I found that I don't really need to append the link to anything, and it still works. But I only tested this in Chromium on Linux so far.

Comment: Does not work with middle mouse click as of now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to achieve `left click` and `middle click` functionality. 
`tabindex` works with any html element so you can use it not the `div`

```
$("#link").on('click', function(e) {
  const hasTargetBlank = $(this).data('target') === '_blank';
  const href = $(this).data('href');

  switch(e.which) {
    // left click
    case 1: {
      if (hasTargetBlank) {
        window.open(href);
      } else {
        window.location = href;
      }
      break;
    }
    // middle click
    case 2: {
      window.open(href);
      break;
    }
    // right click
    case 3: {
      // do what you want to do
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it does not use the native browser behavior. But thanks anyway for the effort!