# Bizarre Error in Chrome Developer Console - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As far as I can tell, this error was not being thrown yesterday on Chrome, and as of this morning, it is. I have not changed any of my browser settings. I have attached a screenshot (after opening/closing Developer Tools window four times):

[image: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS]

This issue is tangentially similar to Stack Overlow post *[Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134)* except that it only occurs when I "Inspect Element" in Chrome. Here are the details I have:

To the best of my ability I undid everything I did since last night (when I did not have this error) and the error persists. When I remove all pre-`<html>` [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code, the error disappears.

When I only remove all the pre-`<html>` PHP code except

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

the error returns.

Since the error seems to involve PHP, I checked my error log, but there are no notices, warnings, nor errors. When I close the Developer Tools window and then open up the window without a page reload, the number of errors increments by one each time.

When I keep the window open, and then reload the page, the page reloads without throwing the error. However, as soon as I close the Developer tools window again, then open it (no page reload), the error is thrown. I checked my site on Firefox with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) enabled, and no errors are thrown, making it seem like a Chrome issue (version 38). My site seems to function normally otherwise. Other sites on device browsed via Chrome (for example, Yahoo) also experience this error.

Also, I have not manually changed any of my browser settings since months ago. As an additional note, this is the **second strange error I have encountered in Chrome** in the last year (see Stack Overflow question *[Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725085)*), to which no one was able to find a solution, even with a bounty offered.

Is there a way to prevent this error, or is this a browser-only issue? On a side note, when I open up Developer Tools in Chrome for Stack Overflow, there is no error thrown, so either Stack Overflow is not coded in PHP or they have a way to prevent this error. I think my site is not affected, but I am not 100% sure, and it makes me nervous :)

Comment: hmm i have noticed this too and read somewhere that the adblock extension is causing it.haven't noticed smth wrong though, everything works as intended, even when the error appears.

Comment: I'm not using adBlock at work, and the chrome nightly is throwing the same error.

Comment: Do you got any Popup blockers or a new plugin or anything alike, does this appear in incognito aswell? Might wanna take a peak at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome

Comment: @Decypher...I just checked and yes, the error still appears when browsing incognito....thanks for the link, which is the "click here" I have near the top of my post :)

Comment: I've also started seeing this the other day. I'm not certain, but believe it coincided with upgrading to 38.0.2125.104.

Comment: @Curtis Mattoon, 38.0.2125.104 is the version of Chrome I'm using too

Comment: Reporting this error Chrome 38.0.2125.104 installed on various machines.. Very annoying.

Comment: Filed report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a form i'm working on and ironically the data isn't submitting to my database but not sure if it's related to this issue...

Comment: @Courtney Jordan, is the form submitting the data on FF? Firebug did not detect this ERR_CACHE_MISS error for my site when I used FF

Comment: Firefox doesn't display the error. On a positive note I just resolved my DB error so the ERR issue wasn't causing that. I did notice the ERR error started to surface with Chromes recent update. I'm going to check out the dev notes to see if they can provide some insight to this conflict.

Comment: We see the same thing on our site and on facebook.com as well. It appears to be just a bug in Chrome that occurs only when you use the dev tools. So far haven't seen any ill effects besides the error message printing.

Comment: It's adblocker. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome

Comment: @RichieRich....I have already seen that post (it's linked in the click here near the top of my post)....that was from 4 years ago...as I stated near the top, I never saw this error message until 2 days ago, and didn't change any browser settings on Chrome, and it just started to appear

Comment: I am not using php and I have the same problem. Pretty sure it is a  bug in Chrome as is also just 'appeared' for me a couple of days ago. Hope they fix this soon...

Comment: This is an old post however I am suffering from the same issue. Currently using Version 53.0.2785.116 (64 bit) on a MacBook Pro. It would seem that it is still an issue and I don't have this problem in Firefox.  FYI: all software including OSX is up to date.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Per the [developers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c23), this error is not an actual failure, but rather "misleading error reports". This bug is fixed in version 40, which is [available on the canary and dev channels as of 25 Oct](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c17).

[Patch](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=184192)

Comment: This thing makes my chrome slow. How could i update to version 40? My chrome says "Version 39.0.2171.71 m" and it is up to date?

Comment: Chrome 40 was released on beta yesterday: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/ You'll want to switch to the beta channel: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: Chrome 40 was officially released and I can confirm that it fixes this error.

Answer (score 56):

On Chrome's latest update (38.0.2125.104 m at the moment), Google added the option to know whether the files loaded to the website were newly downloaded from the server - or read from the local cache.

When an error like yours "hits" the console - you know the files were just downloaded from the server and not read from the local cache. You can recreate this error by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh and erase cache).

It fits your description where Firebug (or equivalents) doesn't fire any errors to the console - whilst Chrome does.

So, the bottom line is - your're just fine and you can ignore this error - it's merely an indicator.

Comment: The error is only reproducible when console is not open. So it somehow is relevant to the console component as well. And you DON'T need to use `ctrl+f5` to reproduce it - it's reproducible on facebook every time you load it as soon as dev console is closed. So your answer barely explains the observed behaviour

Comment: " Google added the option to know whether the files loaded to the website were newly downloaded from the server - or read from the local cache. " ----> I'm almost 100% sure you could do this before the latest update by clicking Inspect Element --> Network, then inspecting the Size column

Comment: Actually, in my case, the Outlook.com website seems to be not working because of this. If I open an Incognito window, it works.

Comment: FWIW, an HTTP 302 vs 200 status would also be an indicator.

Answer (score 12):

Check to see if you have previously disabled caching in Chrome when the developer console is open - the setting is under the console, settings icon > General tab: `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`

Comment: I just checked to make sure, but no, the Disable cache option was/is not selected

Answer (score 6):

Check for the presence of words like "ad", "banner" or "popup" within your file. I removed these and it worked. Based on this post here: [Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome) it seems like Ad Block Plus was the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can recreate the issue in an Incognito tab. If you find that the problem no longer occurs then I would recommend you go through your extensions, perhaps disabling them one at a time. This is commonly the cause as touched on by Nikola

Comment: I checked that after a user made the incognito suggestion (see comment above by Decypher)....the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

I had issues getting through a form because of this error.

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to click the submit button and navigate through the form as usual.