# Stupid error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, yii, cross-browser

I'm developing Web app in Yii framework. I need use `AJAX` in my some pages. So, when I clicked the button (which I *loaded them with AJAX* the **`Google Chrome Developer Tools`** browser says me:

> `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`

How to solve this problem?

P.S: I know it's duplicate question, but I couldn't find the solution for my problem. In some posts users said *use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`N` and try it. it will works.* and/or somebody said: *reload pages with `Ctrl`+`F5` because Google Chrome likes cache everything.*. So, I read all of these topics and applied all solution tips. But there were not help. Please help me...

And also in other browsers some pages not working properly. But only the **`Google Chrome Developer Tools`** returns me the stupid error.

Best.

Comment: The answers you're referring to also specifically mention disabling any ad-blocking software.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Mr.Llama thanks for attention. Yes, I tried but the result the same.

Comment: I think this is a bug in the latest version of Chrome. For me it popped up about one week ago. There is an issue report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599). The issue is not related to php btw.

Comment: so.. when this problem will resolve?

Comment: They added that info to the issue report: This fix will appear in 40.x.y.z versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bizarre error in Chrome --> Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_CACHE\_MISS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cache-miss)

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26653204/916632
(chrome bug fixed in later version)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google declares that this is not a failure, but some "misleading error reports".
This bug will be fixed in version 40 of chrome.

You can read this:

[Chromium forum](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c13)
[Chromium forum](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c17)
[Patch](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=184192)

Comment: At version 49 (as of March 2016), it's still an issue. This did the trick for me:
    session_cache_limiter('none');

Answer (score 5):

It is actually a permission issue. Add these lines in your `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I think your last line is meant to be ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>```

Comment: How is android related to chrome's issue?

Answer (score 2):

It only appeared in my Chrome browser a few days ago too. I checked a few websites I developed in the past that haven't been changed and they also show the same error. So I'd suggest it's not down to your coding, rather a bug in the latest Chrome release.

Comment: Considering I have this error on Google Hangouts, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error with clearing cache and restarting chrome. Hope they will fix it in ver 40.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap that will be the problem. If you want to use same bootstrap file in two locations use it below the header section .(example - inside body)

Note : "specially when you use html editors. "

Thank you.

Comment: it's not answer of the question. also I wrote in the question that, I have already 'checked' all solutions. Thx

Comment: I got same problem then i do some changes in bootstrap file and sorted out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because of the new Google Universal Analytics code, particularly caused by using the Remarketing lists on Analytics.  
Here's how I fixed it.

1) Log into Google Analytics
2) Click "Admin" in top menu
3) In "Property" column, click "Property Settings"
4) Make sure "Enable Display Advertiser Features" is "On"
5) Click "Save" at bottom
6) Click ".js Tracking Info" in left menu
7) Click "Tracking Code"
8) Update your website's tracking code


When you run the debugger again, hopefully it will be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

We get [err_cache_miss](https://appuals.com/fix-err_cache_miss/) error while using the bowser. Its mean there may be a problem with your browser. It due the items in the cache may be unusable or some configurations are not configured correctly. You may get the solution to clear browser data or  Check browser extensions and remove extensions which you felt cause the problem or Resetting your browser or Update your browser or Disabling cache system. These are some tricks to come out this error.

Answer (score -3):

Try loading the website in another web browser such as Safari. Recently had this problem and for some reason, it worked after loading in a different browser.