# Facebook Canvas App on Heroku with Meteor.js - Incomplete Chunked Encoding

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, meteor, facebook-canvas

I have a meteor.js app on Heroku that i'm trying to load into a Facebook Canvas App. The page works great in all browsers but Chrome, where I'm getting an error in the web inspector console: **ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**, and then the page never loads. This happens around 80% of the time, but occasionally does load correctly (upon multiple refreshes).

For simplicity, I've put together the sample Meteor app which replicates the same issues I'm having. Here is the website on heroku: https://fbmeteor.herokuapp.com
And here is the Facebook canvas: https://apps.facebook.com/mymeteortestheroku/

I've searched through and found many similar cases where people have run into the Incomplete Chunked Encoding error in Chrome, and solutions have ranged from [disabling anti-virus](http://thisinterestsme.com/err_incomplete_chunked_encoding/) to [claiming it will be fixed in future Chrome versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494153/stupid-error-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cache-miss).

I've tried all of these and more and am still running into the same issues. On Heroku, I get the following error in my logs:

> heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/"

The reason why I say that this is unique to Heroku is, I tried running the same app hosted on meteor.com and placed it into the Facebook Canvas. This compeltely fixed the issue and I don't see it happening (but I also don't want to host the production app on meteor.com). Here's the website on meteor.com: https://fbmeteortest.meteor.com/

I've also tried running other Node.js implementations (without Meteor) on Heroku and placing them into a Facebook Canvas, and they work fine as well.

For reference, here is the buildpack I'm using on Heroku for Meteor: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Any ideas on why this issue would be happening solely with Meteor.js and Heroku?