# Error during Web Socket handshake

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

Im using websocket that connects to a php process that acts as a chat server.

Upon websocket restart everything goes well , several clients can connect and all is running as expected.

After several hours Suddenly something stops and this is the message shown on chrom console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/echobot' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Cheking the process via SSH
netstat -anp|grep :9000 results are [image: attached(png)]

After that im killing the process and starts it again and everything goes well again.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: There really isn't a lot to go on - but the netstat shows a that there is data in the recv-q on many of the connections - CLOSE_WAIT shows that the far end has closed the connection already and the OS is waiting for your script to close the local end. Normally, you should see nothing in the recv queues unless you program is blocking for a while. It means it is not grabbing data from the OS anymore, and is not detecting the close from the remote end.

Comment: I am currently having the same issues, since 2 days now. We have a websocket server running since over 6 months, and we didnt touch the files since 1 month. Our netstats looks similair, but we do not have `close_wait` in our netstats in that amount (only 2-3).
Did you found already a solution. I probably assume its connected to this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca

Comment: After some research I could probably determine that my server isn't responding to my client, it doesn't send a handshake after the get request.