# Chrome - ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, console

Does anybody know what the following Chrome error is?

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

I have had a look online, but have not found a good answer yet. Somebody said it might be related to the latest Chrome update?

What is it and how can I resolve the issue?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bizarre error in Chrome --> Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_CACHE\_MISS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cache-miss)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, this is a current issue in Chrome. There is an issue report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599).

The fix will appear in 40.x.y.z versions.

Until then? I don't think you can resolve the issue yourself. But you can ignore it. The shown error is only related to the dev tools and does not influence the behavior of your website. If you have any other problems they are not related to this error.

Answer (score 119):

If you are using WebView in Android developing the problem is that you didn't add uses permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue distinct to Chrome, but there are two paths you can take to fix it.

I noticed the error once I added this specific header to my PHP script.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

The error appears to be related to PHP sessions when sending response headers. So according to chromium bug report [424599](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599), this was fixed and you can just update to a newer version of Chrome. But if for some reason you can't or don't want to update, the workaround would be to remove these response headers from your PHP script if possible (that's what I did because it wasn't required).

Comment: I am not using PHP but still have this issue. In general I don't think it makes sense to 'fix' something that is a bug somewhere else (in this case Chrome). Especially if the problem does not really have an impact on the application you are building. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but the "fix" is to update Chrome as I mentioned. The other is just a workaround. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I just dont know if removing information about the Content-Type is something that I would recommend here (but then I am not really familiar with PHP...). Can you be sure that the behavior of your page will be the same afterwards (In all common browsers and versions)? In any case it is interesting that the bug is related to response headers.

Comment: If the content you are returning, whether from php or other, is json it should have the header 'Content-Type: application/json' regardless. I certainly wouldn't modify that to hide a meaningless chrome error if that is the appropriate header to describe the result from a request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Chrome and resolved in latest versions. Please refer https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942440 for more details.