# Vimeo error after going back page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, vimeo

I'm having an strange problem after entering a project and going back to the home.

Here is the [home](http://moejohn.com/?page_id=14913). It works well when you open it but if you click for example on first project and then go back, the page loads all videos the same:

[image]

If I check the console this is the error I'm getting:
    `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS http://player.vimeo.com/video/9956698?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0`

This is the loop:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="post_image">
            <?php $_video_type = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_choose", true);?>
            <?php if($_video_type == "youtube") { ?>
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_link", true);  ?>?wmode=transparent" wmode="Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <?php } elseif ($_video_type == "vimeo"){ ?>
                <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_link", true);  ?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
            <?php } elseif ($_video_type == "self"){ ?> 
                <div class="video"> 
                <div class="mobile-video-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_image", true);  ?>);"></div> 
                <div class="video-wrap"  > 
                    <video class="video" poster="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_image", true);  ?>" preload="auto"> 
                        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_webm", true) != "") { ?> <source type="video/webm" src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_webm", true);  ?>"> <?php } ?> 
                        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_mp4", true) != "") { ?> <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_mp4", true);  ?>"> <?php } ?> 
                        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_ogv", true) != "") { ?> <source type="video/ogg" src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_ogv", true);  ?>"> <?php } ?> 
                        <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/flashmediaelement.swf"> 
                            <param name="movie" value="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
                            <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_mp4", true);  ?>" /> 
                            <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video_format_image", true);  ?>" width="1920" height="800" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="Video thumb" /> 
                        </object> 
                    </video>   
                </div></div> 
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
</article>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome - ERR\_CACHE\_MISS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515991/chrome-err-cache-miss)

Comment: Are you using chrome browser? Or have you install any plugin to your wordpress recently?

Comment: yes I'm using chrome. It has lots of plugins, any in particular could be making this error?

Comment: Did you read the post I linked to?

Comment: @rnevius I'm taking a look at it ;)

Comment: @rnevius The answer there says this error doesn't influence anything in the site, so the repeating videos is not a matter of this error?

Comment: Looks chrome issue. First check in other browser. OR update your chrome version then check once.

Comment: I'm using last version of Chrome :)

Comment: Ok..are you getting same issue in other browsers?