# Can't render dynamically created image in PHP (Apache2)

Tags: php, linux, apache, mime-types, captcha

I'm trying to render captcha Image on a page as follows:

```
<img src="part/captcha_image.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' alt="captcha image">
```

Image is returned in `captcha_image.php` with:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image); //showing the image
```

And on windows machine on xampp it's showing without any problems but on linux with manual apache2 installation image doesn't renders and in browser's developer's tools i see following errors:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` (Shown on chrome and firefox)

`http://localhost/app/part/captcha_image.php?rand=1653484771 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` (only shown on chrome)

What am I missing?

Comment: You're using chrome, correct? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca & https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599

Comment: That's correct. I've tested my page on firefox and edited my question with results (ERR_CACHE_MISS is not shown on firefox)

Comment: Did you install php with gd module?

Comment: @Cheery , good sir you just saved my day! `sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo service apache2 restart` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cheery suggested in comments I was missing [gd module which is responsible for creation and manipulation of image files](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php)
. Command `sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo service apache2 restart` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this question has been answered in the comments. For a problem like this, be sure to turn on detailed error reporting in PHP's configuration, and hit the URL for an image directly in your browser address bar.

If you do that, and in fact the problem is that you needed `gd` and `gd` is missing, then the error page will tell you so.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Am I correct that `error_reporting(-1);` function call turns on detailed reporting?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. But I just keep it on globally using the appropriate setting in `php.ini`, in my development instance of the project.