# Cannot debug a javascript issue in Chrome Developer Tools/Firebug

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple javascript syntax error in one of my pages.

In the Console from Chrome Developer tools I get the following message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( ... my_file.php(line 1799)
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

However, I cannot inspect the page's source. It simply shows in blank, or is not loaded.

I looked into the Resource tab, into the script file and searched for the affected line. Line 1799 has a commented instruction:

```
//location.reload();
```

It doesn't make sense and this is not the first time that I had a report in Chrome only to find out that the problem was in another line or file.

In Firebug nothing is reported, despite the fact that the javascript also does not work.

**What steps could I try to figure out what is this error coming from?**

I already tried:

- Refreshing the page. It's common knowledge that the script only loads after I load the page a second time;
- Inspecting the file's script in the Source Tab - it shows in blank (regardless of how many times I refresh);
- Inspecting the file's script in the Resources Tab - the error shows in a commented line. The line 1799 shows a commented instruction;
- Inspecting the file's script in Firebug shows nothing. No errors are thrown in the Script or in the Console. And yet, the javascript does not work...

**Update**: I fixed the ERR_CACHE_MISS by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (load and delete cache), as suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca).

However, the syntax error (unexpected closing brackets) is still showing up. The location of the faulty line varies with each page refresh, but they show on lines that look fine.

**Update #2**: I fixed the problem. I had to inspect all my script lines and gradually fixed syntax errors (which were away from the rows hinted at by Chrome).

I still have no idea why Firebug did not report me the faulty line, or why Chrome DevTools pointed at the wrong one. This was the part that was most frustrating.

Comment: As your update #2 is an answer, you should add it as such instead of putting it into your question. It's hard to tell what's actually happening without seeing any code. If you still want to get a proper answer to why the DevTools or Firebug didn't point you to the right place, please post a URL or a small example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from update #2)

I fixed the problem. I had to inspect all my script lines and gradually fixed syntax errors one by one (which were away from the rows hinted at by Chrome).

While I was fixing different lines, the same line (which apparently looks correct) kept showing up with an error.

Then, after I fixed a particular line, the error from line 1799 was not reported anymore.

I still have no idea why Firebug did not report me the faulty line, or why Chrome DevTools pointed at the wrong one. This was the part that was most frustrating.