# Realtime bandwidth monitor with PHP/flot

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flot

I found cool realtime bandwidth monitor here: http://www.codejungle.org/site/Realtime+bandwidth+meter+with+php+and+jquery.html

What I tried to do is to modify the code so that it could show two series: download and upload speed.

I changed only the last few lines of code in data.php:

```
echo '[
{
    label: "download",
    data: ['.implode($_SESSION['rx'], ",").']
},
{
    label: "upload",
    data: ['.implode($_SESSION['tx'], ",").']
}
];';
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, what's wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

Loose the outer brackets (they are already in the `onDataReceived` function) and the semicolon at the end:

```
echo '
{
    label: "download",
    data: ['.implode($_SESSION['rx'], ",").']
},
{
    label: "upload",
    data: ['.implode($_SESSION['tx'], ",").']
}
';
```

Comment: It didn't help, still blank plot.

Comment: @skaarj, when you checked your javascript console for errors, what did it say?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: That is not really an error, it just says that your data was loaded from the server and not from the cache. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26408931/2610249).