# Why isn't this session form working?

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have this login form set out that converts the $_POST data into $_SESSION data. I then use this data to determine whether or not the user should be logged in, however it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

*** I checked my browser's cookies, and it has the session token stored (if that helps)

login.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="page.php" method="post">

        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $submit = $_POST['submit'];

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
        }

        ?>

</form>
```

page.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

        $username = isset($_SESSION["username"]) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "";
        $password = isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : "";

        $submit = isset($_SESSION["submit"]) ? $_SESSION["submit"] : "";


        if(($username == "username") && ($password == "password") && ($submit == "Submit")) {
            echo "You are logged in";
        } else {
            echo "Denied access";
        }
?>
```

I get this error on pages that include session_start();

[image]

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca), it is a bug caused by Chrome that is a misleading error report, and doesn't affect anything.

Comment: You didn't start the session.

Comment: Haha thanks, stupid error :D

Comment: I just added session_start(); and it still isn't working

Comment: you also missed `action="page.php"` quotes around action

Comment: @Fred-ii- we are here to solve this type of problems of others and our own i think.

Comment: I have quotes around it now, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">

    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />


 </form>
```

page.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
    }
    $username = isset($_SESSION["username"]) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "";
    $password = isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : "";

    $submit = isset($_SESSION["submit"]) ? $_SESSION["submit"] : "";


    if(($username == "username") && ($password == "password") && ($submit == "Submit"))        {
        echo "You are logged in";
    } else {
        echo "Denied access";
    }
?>
```

Comment: this code shuold work +1

Comment: @mightyspaj is it showing any error?

Comment: Yep, when I login to page.php it shows this: http://gyazo.com/66952644690b5a03bdfa8e149259c3bd

Comment: The same error also occurs on login.php before I even try logging in (This is when I have session_start(); included)

Comment: @mightyspaj can you please share the error,i can't access you screenshot

Comment: @mightyspaj you need to start the session only in page.php ,clear your cache and restart your browser.Try with other browsers also.

Comment: I tried that and it still isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68703/discussion-between-avm-and-mightyspaj).

Comment: It's ok, someone just got the answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good to hear :) but i couldn't find a difference b/w my answer and your accepted answer

Comment: Haha another stupid mistake... I read your question incorrectly and didn't even notice that you did that. Since you were the one who posted the answer first I will give you the tick :)

Answer (score 1):

when you give action on form `submit` to another page `page.php`. So, why you get form data on same page ?

**Please try this it will work :**

**HTML Form :**

```
<form action=page.php method="post">

    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />


 </form>
```

**page.php :**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
    }
    $username = isset($_SESSION["username"]) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "";
    $password = isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : "";

    $submit = isset($_SESSION["submit"]) ? $_SESSION["submit"] : "";


    if(($username == "username") && ($password == "password") && ($submit == "Submit"))        {
        echo "You are logged in";
    } else {
        echo "Denied access";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start();` at the top of the pages and fix the action.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<form action="" method="post">

        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $submit = $_POST['submit'];

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
            header('page.php');
        }

        ?>

</form>
```

And

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $username = isset($_SESSION["username"]) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "";
        $password = isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : "";

        $submit = isset($_SESSION["submit"]) ? $_SESSION["submit"] : "";


        if(($username == "username") && ($password == "password") && ($submit == "Submit")) {
            echo "You are logged in";
        } else {
            echo "Denied access";
        }
?>
```

Comment: I did that, and it still isn't working.

Comment: You are storing the session on login.hp but the form action is page.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to start the session using `session_start()` in form page.Also you need to use header to send session to the login.php. Use the code below

```
<?php session_start();?>
<form action="" method="post">

        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $submit = $_POST['submit'];

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
            header('page.php');
        }

        ?>

</form>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your form sends a post to page.php. Therefore, you will need to move session conditional to page.php.

Alteratively, you could send the form to yourself and redirect afterwards:

```
<?php session_start();?>

<form action="" method="post">

        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $submit = $_POST['submit'];

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['submit'] = $submit;
            header('page.php');
        }

    $username = isset($_SESSION["username"]) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "";
    $password = isset($_SESSION["password"]) ? $_SESSION["password"] : "";

    $submit = isset($_SESSION["submit"]) ? $_SESSION["submit"] : "";


    if(($username == "username") && ($password == "password")) {
        echo "You are logged in";
    } else {
        echo "Denied access";
    }

        ?>

</form>
```