# Catch mouse click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, mouseevent

I have a page with many `iframe` and I should open a `drop-down menu` on top of all them by append the menu at the top body. 
Problem is that how can I `catch` the next click of the mouse to close the menu? Because I don't know in which frame it will be I can't add an `click listener` to the right `iframe`. 
Is there any way to catch the `click event` instead of the click event on the target element?

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jAP4C/) - if I click inside the iframe the menu will not be removed!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool - I must not simulate a click but I want catch the next mouse click

Comment: You should replicate your issue on jsFiddle to make your question clearer. If your issue is regarding click on iframe, you could use: http://jsfiddle.net/cVcEz/

Comment: @A.Wolff - I have added the jsFiddle example

Comment: For all that downvoted, provide me the answer!

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik Be aware, no one has to provide you an answer...

Comment: @A.Wolff - Sure, no one must give me an answer, but I think that if one downvote is because he thinks that the question is useless or with an easy solution...

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik You should have provided relevant code in question. Now i guess some guys didn't understood your issue in first place which is that iframes don't fire click event on parent document level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this kind of workaround which will work on any iframe (cross domain too). But would need more testing:

### --DEMO--

```
$(focusWindow);

$('iframe').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(window).on('blur', iframeclicked);
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(window).off('blur', iframeclicked);
    if($(document.activeElement).is('iframe'))
        focusWindow();
});

function iframeclicked(){
     $("#myMenu").remove();
}

function focusWindow(){
    $('<div/>').attr('tabindex',-1).prependTo('body').focus().remove();
}

//$(window).mouseenter(focusWindow); << removed it
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I haven't understand the `focusWindow` function.

Comment: This is just a workaround for cross browser behaviour to set focus on window once DOM is ready. You could find better way and could for example handle case where e.g an input as autofocus set, etc... This would need more testing for sure. Indeed the idea is to check for window on blur event which is fired when an iframe (cross domain or not) is clicked. But as this event can be fired from multiple causes, we handle it to check if user is currently over an iframe on page or not, that's the idea behind it

Comment: That's said, if all your iframes are from same domain, better would be to handle it from iframe code, targeting parent document function

Comment: now I understand how it works! The frame have dynamic source and some times cross domain, so the proposed version is ok. I only changed the `appendTo('body')` with the `prependTo('body')` otherwise at opening of the menu the iframe scrolls down ;-)

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik Prepending element sounds better indeed, thx for the feedback :)

Comment: Another improvement, in the `iframeclicked` function I have added the following line to unbind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events: `$('iframe').off('mouseenter mouseleave');`