# Auto-click script within a browser

Tags: javascript

A user claimed to have gotten such script running without having to leave the computer i.e. the auto-clicking action happens hidden in the browser:

http://forum.dashnet.org/discussion/206/autoclickers/p2#Comment_8954

Is that possible? If so, could the experts show me some pointers so I could learn to do some scripting for that purpose?

Comment: This is entirely off topic here, but if you're curious, just inspect the `Game` javascript variable from the console if memory serves me well.

Comment: unattended events could be triggered via iMacro firefox addon.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6158050/3802940

Answer (score 2):

It is a very simple task to dispatch and event with javascript.

For a modern method see [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEventt)

```js
var clickMe = document.getElementById('clickMe');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('I was clicked');
}, true);

setTimeout(function() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click'),
    canceled = !clickMe.dispatchEvent(event);

  if (canceled) {
    console.log('Click event was canceled');
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="clickMe">Click Me</div>
```

Output after 5 seconds

```
I was clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clickMe = document.getElementById('clickMe');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('I was clicked');
}, true);

setTimeout(function() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click'),
    canceled = !clickMe.dispatchEvent(event);

  if (canceled) {
    console.log('Click event was canceled');
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="clickMe">Click Me</div>
```