# How to force click button in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

Something like this but instead for clicking the button have it done by calling it programmatically.

```
<script>

 function myFunction() 
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

button onclick="myFunction()">Click me

id="demo"

Comment: To click an element, use `element.click()`.

Comment: Show us some code you have already, what you tried etc. Without that, we can explain to you what you did wrong and what you should do instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically click a link with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-programmatically-click-a-link-with-javascript)

Comment: The user is asking a high-level question about a topic, as such the lack of code is okay. However, if you do have some code to post, this would enhance the question.

Comment: Also: [Click a button programmatically - JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278469/click-a-button-programmatically-js)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711051/auto-click-script-within-a-browser/24712697#24712697

Comment: But why do you need to issue a `click event` when you could just èxecute the `click handler` directly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "click for itself" is the right way to think about this problem. A better way would be to modularize the functionality of the button click as such:

```
doOnClickButton()
```

Then, when the page loads, simply execute this function.

Example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doOnClickButton();
})
```

Comment: The OP is asking about JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is Javascript. Yes this can also be done in vanilla js which is fine, but there's also nothing wrong with using jQuery. All it is is a wrapper around Javascript to make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Following the nmg49 answer, you can do it without jQuery using the DOMContentLoaded event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    doOnClickButton();
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply put, just skip the button part and call the function on page load. If you were doing this, use a JavaScript such as the one shown.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  alert("Hello world!");
}, 1);
```

Comment: This doesn't cover what the OP is asking