# Stop theJit dragging when mouse exits canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, thejit

I am using **theJit** as **SpaceTree** to visualize some information (Who'd guessed that...)

Problem is, when users are **panning the graph** and dragging the **mouse outside** of the canvas jit doesn't recognizes it and **keeps on dragging**. When the user comes **back into the area** of the canvas it is **still in drag-mode** and keeps on panning. This behavior is also **observable in their [Space-Tree-Example](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html).**

*(Just to clarify - I am panning the whole graph; I am not dragging a node to some target location...)*

I can bind to $('#container').mouseleave() via **jQuery**, but how to I **tell jit to stop dragging?**

(The mouseOver and mouseLeave handlers provided by jit (jit.Events.*) itself are bound to the individual nodes and thus not really helpful in this case)

Anybody got an Idea?

Cheers,

Corelgott_

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to do it... definitely not the cleanest / nicest way of doing it, but it works at least:

When the mouse leaves the the box of the jit canvas I simulate a complete mouse-out event and send it to jit.

By using this code "[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050)" like this:

```
    $('#infovis').mouseleave(function(e) {
        simulate($('canvas')[0], 'mouseup')            
    });
```

it stops when the mouse exists the info-vis-<div>

Hopefully that saves somebody some time in the future!

Cheers,

Corelgott