# How do I simulate a click on a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to be able to rig a shortcut to a youtube controll button. I want to be able to click on the left and right arrow to activate "Previous video" and "Next video" on a playlist. I used to be easily able to do it myself, but they made some changes and since those I can't quite replicate what i used to have working.

I use the Google Chrome [Shortkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) Plug-in to manage my short cut keys. I make the right key execute a javascript code only on "https://www.youtube.com*"

The problem reside in the script to execute. I used to simply do a document.getElementById but now they use class instead of id and I cant get it to work. Their buttons are divs and they go like this:

```
<div class="ytp-button ytp-button-prev" role="button" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="6050" style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div class="ytp-button ytp-button-next" role="button" aria-label="Next" tabindex="6051" style="display: inline-block;">
```

My code actualy comes from another [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158050/1692889)

Still, if I put all of that together to make the folowing code it doesn't work.

```
simulate(document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-button ytp-button-prev"), "click");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array, since you can have multiple elements with the same class name.  You can pick them by `document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-button ytp-button-prev")[index]`

Comment: It gives my an index is not defined, should i put a 0 instead?

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyname) returns a live [*HTMLCollection*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0), which is very different to an Array. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can target the element then trigger a click event like this:

```
$( ".ytp-button-prev" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Answers should explain why they fix the OPs issue. Pushing a particular library that is neither tagged or in the question is not good form. If you are going to do that, you should at least note which one. The *$* variable name is used by a few.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not the best solution for all our projects, but for simulate events it's not bad option

```
(function($){
    $('.element').click();
    // same for others ex: $('.element').keyup();
})(jQuery);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/h0po3q3w/

Answer (score 0):

Jason has your answer, but an alternative is to use *document.querySelector*. If there is only one button with those classes, or you want the first one, then:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.ytp-button.ytp-button-prev');
```