# Binding Magnific Popup plugin to a button (besides the gallery element itself)

Tags: jquery, lightbox, magnific-popup

I successfully implemented my `Magnific Popup` plugin, binding it to the gallery element (a `div` containing a set of `img` elements wrapped up in `a` elements). But I also want the lightbox to appear when clicking on a separate "see gallery" button.

I can't see anywhere how to achieve that in [the documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html). Is it even possible?

Comment: Please provide your actual HTML and JS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just trigger click event via JS, e.g.:

```
$('.popup-gallery').find('a').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Just what I need, thanks! Any idea why the scroll position of the page changes (to about one screen upwards) when opening the gallery this way, while it remains unchanged by opening it by clicking on one of the pictures?

Comment: Hard to tell without link to the page with issue. Do parent elements have any kind of links with #hashes?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when the "see gallery" button is clicked you want to trigger the click event on the element that normally opens the popup, so that the popup will open. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript) for some good ways of doing this.