# programically activate gmails older and newer email buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

[image]

These two buttons are from gmail. They let you go left and right through more emails.

How do I click these buttons using javascript and jquery? I'm willing to use extra libraries if necessary. I'm trying to make a shortcut that lets me use keyboard buttons to click and go to older or newer emails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript has some good ways of doing this.

Comment: None of the methods in that post worked :(

Comment: Well I don't see any possibilities, because it is google and they have well maintained security. I have no solution sorry!

Answer (score 2):

let me know if it helps:-

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
        break;    

        case 39: // right
        break;    

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Comment: No this doesn't, I want to click the button using javascript, So far trying jquery .click and simulating a mouse click do not work.

Comment: @CharlesHaro you said you are trying to make a shortcut. if you want to click that button using javascript you can do like this `var myEl = document.getElementById('myelement');

myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello world');
}, false);`

Comment: @CharlesHaro if click is defined you can simply use this `document.getElementById("myelement").click();`

Comment: This does not work on the gmail buttons. There is something else going on. Go try it for youself

Comment: @CharlesHaro can you add your html in `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 2):

you aren't going to be able to just sit a script on gmail.  You will either need to create this in google scripts or will need to use something like [Gmailr](https://github.com/jamesyu/gmailr) in order to inject the script into the DOM

Comment: are you sure? All the other buttons I've tried have worked fine, like the compose button I can make a shortcut for that

Comment: Bradgnar, that's not true.  bookmarklets can be inject javascript into any page including Gmail.

Comment: its not inserting the js that is the problem, its just that every thing i've tried does not work for clicking that button.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out from the JS console. No jquery required, so you wont have to manually inject the jQuery library to get it to work:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-tooltip='Newer']")[0].click()
```

... Thing is, the whole DOM is minimized, so I cant guarantee that any IDs or class-names will remain the same from one day to the next... I bet the tooltip will stay the same for longer, though :)