# onclick event on <audio> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, onclick, element

Given the following markup:

```
<audio controls onclick="alert('hi')">
    <source src="/url/track.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  
</audio>
```

I get no response from the onclick event. Seems like all the onclick events are bound to the player controls.

My goal is to run a separate function when the user hits "play".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `onplay` attribute is what you're looking for.

```
<audio onplay="myFunction()">...</audio>
```

Here's some [article on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp) about it

Answer (score 0):

You can place an invisible div over the audio element:

```
<script>
    function catchClick(){
        alert("hi");
    }
</script>

<div onclick="catchClick()" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;width:300px;height:30px;">
</div>
<audio controls>
    <source src="/url/track.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Then, in the catchClick function you can pass the mouse clicks to the audio element via this method [How to simulate a mouse click using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript)