# How can I option-click an element in a Codeception test?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have an app that allows for a different behavior when a button is clicked while the option key is held down. I am trying to test the functionality with an acceptance tester, using `$I->click()` but I don't see any way to add modifiers like I can with pressKey.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to figure out a workaround for this, based on this SO answer:

[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript)

```
$I->waitForJS('var target = $("span")[0]; var event = target.ownerDocument.createEvent("MouseEvents"); event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, target.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, false, false, 0, null); target.dispatchEvent(event); return true;', 3);
```

This will option click the first `span` element. I hard coded in all the values for simplification, but maybe someone wants to write a wrapper for the codeception project.