# How to programmatically make a line chart point active/highlighted - update

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679293/how-to-programmatically-make-a-line-chart-point-active-highlighted) to the question above, which works for Chart.js v2.0 beta but, for other reasons, I have to use at least v2.6.0. Does anyone have any insight as to how this style of solution could be implemented in this newer version? Is this something that could be implemented using a plugin?

Comment: Actually, found a way to do it: see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xw8J/1158/). However, there must be more elegant ways to get the ticks/axis labels than `points[0]._xScale.ticks`, and similarly there must be a better way to get the bare data array rather than calling `this._data` on the controller. If anybody with some insight knows, that would be useful.

Comment: Update: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8xw8J/1164/) is reasonable, but a better method than `var scale = this.chart.scales['x-axis-'+datasetIndex] || this.chart.scales['x-axis-0']` would be good.

Comment: Sorted: [decent working version](http://jsfiddle.net/8xw8J/1167/). Hope this helps someone else.