# How to select a point on a Line Chart of Chart.js using Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

When i select a point in the chart using

```
let activeElement:Array<any> = this.lineChart.getElementAtEvent(data);
```

i can get the values, after getting the values i use

```
 el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"});
```

to scroll to the row in the grid which i want to highlight.

[image]

Now i am trying to select or highlight a point on the line chart when i select the specific row.

How can i do that using javascript?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687291/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @WhiteHat. I tired but its not working. I tried many different changes but none of them work. i am getting the following error

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'highlightPoints' of undefined`