# Debounce feature selection in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am working with a map that uses a large set of vector features. In some browsers, there is significant lag when the OpenLayers is handling `pointermove` events interactions. For example:

```
function selectOnHover(map, handler, styleFn) {
    var selectMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
        style: styleFn
    });

    map.addInteraction(selectMove);
    selectMove.on('select', handler);
}
```

In other situations that handle continuous input (e.g. handling scroll events) and require significant processing, I would normally [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) the handler for the event - so that significant work is only done when the input has paused (in this case, determining the intersecting features). **Is there a way to insert a debounce between browser event dispatch and OpenLayers checking intersections without circumventing OpenLayers interaction handling?**

*I've tried* handling the pointermove/mousemove events directly, debouncing them (redispatching manually created [synthetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript) events) and then using the interaction's condition to handle only the synthetic ones. This worked except that Internet Explorer's synthetic events weren't picked up by OpenLayers.

*I'm considering* circumventing OpenLayers interaction - for example by using  [forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) and manually updating the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, even using the standard API you can wrap a select interaction into a custom interaction and *debounce* the `handleEvent` function:

```
var app = {};
app.DebounceSelect = function() {
  this.selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
  });

  var handleEventDebounce = debounce(function(evt) {
    return ol.interaction.Select.handleEvent.call(this.selectInteraction, evt);
  }.bind(this), 100);

  ol.interaction.Interaction.call(this, {
    handleEvent: function(evt) {
        handleEventDebounce(evt);
      // always return true so that other interactions can
      // also process the event
      return true;
    }
  });
};
ol.inherits(app.DebounceSelect, ol.interaction.Interaction);

app.DebounceSelect.prototype.setMap = function(map) {
  this.selectInteraction.setMap(map);
};

var select = new app.DebounceSelect();
map.addInteraction(select);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9nbrye8/3/

For reference an example on how to write custom interactions: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/custom-interactions.html

And the documentation for [ol.interaction.Select.handleEvent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#.handleEvent)

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize that `handleEvent` would fire even when the `condition` returned `false`.

Comment: Yes, the check is done inside [handleEvent](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/fd39415/src/ol/interaction/selectinteraction.js#L266-L269).