# Is it possible to selectively pass DOM events through overlapping canvases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a web page with two canvases sitting on top of one another:

```
<style>
canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<canvas id="first" width=800 height=600></canvas>
<canvas id="second" width=800 height=600></canvas>
```

(Full example [here](https://jsbin.com/giqiyuqute/10/edit?html,css,console,output).)

If I register `mousedown` handlers for both canvases:

```
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  console.log('first canvas mousedown');
});

document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  console.log('second canvas mousedown');
});
```

and click on them, then I only see `second canvas mousedown` logged. This makes sense since it's on top.

I'd like the event handler for the `second` canvas to have a first crack at handling the event but, if it doesn't care about it, let it pass through to the event handler for the `first` canvas, which is underneath it.

In reality these `<canvas>`es are parts of independent React components, so it's not trivial to unify the event handlers.

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript

Comment: This is likely completely wrong, but I thought that I remembered that returning false from the handler passed it through to the next responding object.  I'm likely remembering some other context where this is true, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (albeit tedious) to recreate a new event object that mirrors the contents of the first, and then dispatch to the other element, e.g.:

```
var pass = false;  // toggles on each event

first.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  output.innerHTML = "first";
});

second.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  pass = !pass;
  if (pass) {
    var fields = ['screenX', 'screenY', 'clientX', 'clientY',
                  'ctrlKey', 'altKey', 'shiftKey', 'metaKey',
                  'button', 'buttons', 'relatedTarget', 'region'];
    var opts = {};
    fields.forEach(function(f) {
        if (f in e) {
           opts[f] = e[f];
        }
    });
    var copy = new MouseEvent(e.type, opts);
    first.dispatchEvent(copy);
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "second";
  }
});
```

There are other properties from the `MouseEvent`'s super-interfaces that you might want to copy too.

demo at https://jsfiddle.net/070ckbra/2/