# How to do a mouse click on a div or certain coordinates with console?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making some automation script. I could imitate the mouse-click using that automation tools but the coordinates changes over device so I rather make it through browser console.

I could do it with normal `<button>` by using `element.click()` but I couldn't do it with `<div>`

What I want to do is click the start button (はじめから) using console like `element.click()`
[image: ss]

you could try it [here](http://game.granbluefantasy.jp/)

So far, I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('start').click();
```

and

```
a = document.getElementById('start').getBoundingClientRect();
document.elementFromPoint(((a.width / 2) + a.left), ((a.height / 2) + a.top)).click();
```

but nothing happens

Is it possible to do this with browser console?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the `.click()` function is from jQuery. Thus, you would need to get the jQuery element, like this : `$('#start').click()`

Comment: Why don't you trigger the same function that the click triggers instead of clicking on the page from console?

Comment: @JustARandomProgrammer I guess OP wants to click on a button where the inner code of the event in unknown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript)

Comment: @Seblor I could use `.click()` just fine on `<button>` without jQuery. And I've tried the "simulate" from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript but it still does [nothing](http://i.imgur.com/J7TVljb.png)

Answer (score 1):

The page has somehow, in some way, disabled event bubbling and propagation, I suppose.

I tried the below code in stackoverflow console and the page's console, but only stackoverflow's console is having respond.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked' + e.target);
});

document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: interesting click finder, but still doesn't help in my case :(

Comment: Even after implementing the code from console, you can't log anything into console even after manually clicking (it should log something). So I guess you just can't do automation there (maybe you can, but I don't know how).