# Chrome extension: Focus input field on main page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have one HTML page with input box and button. I want to have a chrome extension that can focus on the input element.

HTML page -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="box" />
        <button type="button" onclick="clicked()">Click</button>
        <script>
            //document.getElementsByName("box")[0].focus(); <--- this works. But I don't want this.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My injected script -

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response){
    if(message.action==="start"){
            document.getElementsByName("box")[0].focus(); //<---want this to work. Currently unable to :(
            console.log("started");
    }
});
```

I get the *started* log but my element is not focused.

Rest files (i.e. popup.html and popup.js) not shown because they are working fine and irrelevant to this.

I tried simulating mouse click event on the input element (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27761213/4428377)) but that method also failed.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Open to jquery based solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of document.getElementsByName("box")[0]?

Comment: At the start, it is nothing.

Comment: Try `"run_at": "document_end"` in your manifest.json. See docs about [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for description.

Comment: @Deliaz Did not help.:(

Comment: Have you tried surrounding it with `setTimeout`, like `setTimeout(()=>{document.getElementsByName("box")[0].focus()}, 0);` ?

Answer (score 0):

send message when HTML document is ready.

Comment: I am sending message when all things are ready and it is not working.