# Any way to replace mousedown event in browser

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve a function, that is, press a key to achieve a mouse down, and then slide the touchpad to text selection. I do not know whether this feature can be implemented in the browser.

Comment: I think we can save one mousedown, and send it to function. But I don't know how to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript