# How to simulate click event for tinyMCE v6x custom toolbar button programmatically

Tags: tinymce

This is simple enough in earlier version of tinyMCE, but I can't find a way to make it work in v6x (suggested answers here only apply to earlier versions, that I can see)

Here's my button:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('newButton', (editor, url) => {
   editor.ui.registry.addButton('newButton', {
      text: 'Click me',
      enabled: true,
      onAction: () => {
         alert('You clicked me')
      }
   })
   return {
   getMetadata: () => ({
      name: 'newButton',
      url: ''
   })
}
});

tinymce.init({
   selector: "textarea",
   plugins: "newButton",
   toolbar1: "newButton"
});
```

This works fine - click the button and you get an alert telling you you have. What I want to do now is call this click event from code (JaveScript) - I was hoping

```
tinymce.activeEditor.buttons['newButton'].onclick();
```

would work, as it does for - say - the "code" plugin; i.e. add this plugin (and button) to the editor and calling

```
tinymce.activeEditor.buttons['code'].onclick();
```

simulates clicking the toolbar button. So... how can I "click" my own custon toolbar button?

[edit] well.. that last line did work, I swear it did. Now it doesn't. wt.. :(

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the "right" way (well, I know it isn't!) but I've found a way that works :)

First, I need a way to identify/find my custom button. I figured out tinymce renders them as div elements, and using

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('button');
divs.forEach((div) => {
  console.log(div.innerHTML);
})
```

I am able to identify it and find the HTML used - it is not graced with an id, but we can use the innerHTML property (as identified) to get it and then simulate a click- viz:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('button');
divs.forEach((div) => {
  // NB 'DOC' is the text property of my custom button
  if (div.innerHTML === '<span class="tox-tbtn__select-label">DOC</span>') {
     // now we can simulate a click on it:
     var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
     });
     div.dispatchEvent(evt);
     return;
  }
})
```

(Thanks to the second answer, by Derek, here:
[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050)
for the simulate click code)

[edit] better to use a for-loop rather than forEach as there's no sensible way to break out of the latter - that "return" doesn't actually do anything.